# GridView text field data posting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Not getting text field values into grid view. Only row increases but I do not get the text.

This is the code that I have for the purpose.

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    bool flag = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridVIEWData();
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt1;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void gobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
        dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"];


        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Product"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
        dr["Size"] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem;
        dr["Case"] = casetxt.Text;
        dr["Weight"] = TextBox1.Text;
        dr["Price"] = TextBox2.Text;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

        Session["dtInSession"] = dt1;    
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt1;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }

    private void gridVIEWData()
    {
        dt1.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Case", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
        Session["dtInSession"] = dt1;
    }
```

Please Can any one help me

Comment: I don't think we can find out what's wrong only from the code you posted. Could you show us the aspx as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
 **I hope you looking for something like this**

 protected void BindGridview1()
{
    DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["od"];
    dtt.Columns.Add("BookingNO", typeof(string));
    dtt.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
    dtt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
    dtt.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
    dtt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
    dtt.Columns.Add("PendingQty", typeof(string));

    for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtt.NewRow();
        dr["BookingNO"] = string.Empty;
        dr["ItemName"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Price"] = string.Empty;
        dr["PendingQty"] = string.Empty;
        dtt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    dtt = dt;
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtt;
    gvDetails.DataBind();


    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        TextBox BookingNO = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("BookingNO");
        TextBox ItemName = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("ItemName");
        TextBox Size = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Size");
        TextBox Unit = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Unit");
        TextBox Price = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Price");
        //TextBox DueDate = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("DueDate");
        TextBox PendingQty = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("PendingQty");
        BookingNO.Text = Session["BookingNO1"].ToString();
        ItemName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ItemName"].ToString();
        Size.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Size"].ToString();
        Unit.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Unit"].ToString();
        Price.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString();
        //DueDate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DueDate"].ToString();
        PendingQty.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PendingQty"].ToString();

    }

}
```